# Meaning of the mitzvah to not eat Gid Hanashe

Tags: mitzvah, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, vayishlach, gid-hanashe

Why is the fact that the angel dislodged Yaakov's hip a reason not to eat the gid hanashe? What is the connection, since what happened was to a person and the gid hanashe is part of an animal? What's the meaning behind this mitzvah?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thanks for sharing the question. Consider registering your account to best utilize all of the features of the site. Consider also familiarizing yourself with the nature of the site, with this short [Beginners' Guide](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775). Hopefully well see you around the site.

Answer (score 5):

The **Sefer Hachinuch**  has a known explanation in **Mitsva  3:**

> משרשי מצוה זו, כדי שתהיה רמז לישראל, שאף על פי שיסבלו צרות רבות בגלות מיד העמים ומיד בני עשו, יהיו בטוחים שלא יאבדו, אלא לעולם יעמד זרעם ושמם, ויבא להם גואל ויגאלם מיד צר. **ובזכרם תמיד ענין זה על יד המצוה שתהיה לזכרון, יעמדו באמנתם ובצדקתם לעולם.**  ורמז זה הוא לפי שאותו מלאך שנלחם עם יעקב אבינו, שבא בקבלה (בר''ר עח) שהיה שרו של עשו, רצה לעקרו ליעקב מן העולם הוא וזרעו ולא יכול לו, (שם לב כו) וצערו בנגיעת הירך. וכן זרע עשו מצער לזרע יעקב, ולבסוף תהיה להם תשועה מהם. וכמו שמצינו (שם שם לב) באב שזרחה לו השמש לרפאתו ונושע מן הצער, כן יזרח לו השמש של משיח וירפאנו מצערנו ויגאלנו במהרה בימינו, אמן. . ‏

Despite the suffering of the Galut,  inflicted by nations,  by the offspring of Esav,  Israel would never disappear. The offspring and the name of Israel will always remain. A savior will come. **As long as Jews perform this Mitsva, they remember this issue and remain strong in their believe and their righteousness.**  There is an allusion in the traditional teaching that the Angel was the  representative angel of Esav. He wished to eradicate Yaakov and his offspring from the world, understood that he cannot make this and inflicted to him suffering by meeting the hip.  The relationship between Israel and the offspring of Esav, the offspring of Esav causes suffering to Israel, but finally they would be rescued from them. The recovery of Yaakov with the sunrise is an allusion to Mashiach. The sun of the Mashiach will rise and heal our hurts and rescue us in the near future...